# Android Library Projects on Windows and Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, noclassdeffounderror

I'm asking this question on behalf of my team of two Android devs. I use Windows and my partner uses a Macbook. When sharing a project through Git, the `classpaths` accidentally got messed up. Here are a few observations:

- The library projects referenced (working initially) can't be resolved anymore.
- When adding through the Projects tab in 'Java Build Path', the libraries can be found.
- But the app crashes (due to `NoClassDefFoundError`), again pointing towards a messy build path structure.
- Initially referenced library projects on the Mac used to appear directly in the build path as JARs. Now they do under Android Dependencies, which is weird (the former more).
- On the Windows, the above JARs have always been under Dependencies and Referenced Libraries.

I'd like to resolve this issue in a way that we can share the project on Git and work seamlessly in the future. :)

Comment: have u know why NoClassDefFoundError is come there is some resign so u understand how that come java version and so on issue

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, @NaveenTamrakar.

Comment: first check java version of bath machine and check lib added in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to:

- not version `.classpath`,
- version a classpath *template*
- generate the right classpath depending on the current platform where the code is checked out.

That is called a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309), here a `smudge` script, which will be called automatically (hence the "seamless" aspect) on `git checkout`, and will generate the actual `.classpath` (otherwise not versioned and add in the `.gitignore`)

[image: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/book/08-customizing-git/images/smudge.png]

<sup>(image shown in "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/)")</sup>

Note that you can easily remove  (without deleting it locally) the `.classpath` from the repo:

```
git rm --cached -- .classpath
git add -u .
git commit -m "Delete .classpath"
git push
```

Comment: The `.classpath` was added to the commits by mistake. Also, I'm pretty  new to Git and haven't used a `smudge` script before. I'll surely read more about it and fashion one for my project. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @SlashG you can easily remove it (without deleting it): `git rm --cached -- .classpath; git add -u . ; git commit -m "Delete .classpath"`

Comment: @SlashG a smudge script can be written in any script language you want. A bash script will work both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the remove tip (especially)! I hope it works well.

Comment: @SlashG OK. I have included the removal process in the answer for more visibility.